# Mongoose: How to use ObjectId to link models?

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm using Express, Mongoose and Mongodb. I have two Models, one for User, and another one for Review, like so:

```js
var User = mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: String
});
mongoose.model("User", User);

var Review = mongoose.Schema({
  foodRating: Number,
  serviceRating: Number,
  locationRating: Number,
  wouldReturn: boolean
});
mongoose.model("Review", Review);
```

I want to link both models, in a way that the reviews belongs to the user.

I read about ObjectId, but it is not clear how to implement it. Should I create it, then use it, like so:

```
const MyObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
```

then override the _id of the model I want to link to my first model with it?

```js
var User = mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: String,
  review: [MyObjectId] // retrieves model below from its _id:MyObjectId
});
mongoose.model("User", User);

var Review = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: MyObjectId, // overriding _id with ObjectId
  foodRating: Number,
  serviceRating: Number,
  locationRating: Number,
  wouldReturn: boolean
});
mongoose.model("Review", Review);
```

Is this correct? Or how would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this from the mongoose docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Basically, what you want to do is:

```
const MyObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

var User =  mongoose.Schema({

    firstName:String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    review: [MyObjectId] // retrieves model below from its _id:MyObjectId
});

mongoose.model('User', User);

var Review =  mongoose.Schema({
    user: { type: MyObjectId, ref: 'User' } // overriding _id with ObjectId
    foodRating: Number,
    serviceRating: Number,
    locationRating: Number,
    wouldReturn: boolean,

});
mongoose.model('Review', Review);
```

Once you that is done the _id from the User document will be stored in the user field of the Review document. Then you can do something like this:

```
Review.
    findOne({ foodRating: 4 }).
    populate('user').
    exec((err, review) => {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      console.log('The user is %s %s', review.user.firstName, review.userLastName);
      // prints "The user is So-and-so"
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for.